# Error while printing in octave

Tags: octave

When i am trying to print variables or even for 'help < topic >' commands, I am getting this error in octave.

```
octave-3.6.4.exe:66> help minimize
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x170000, State 0x10000
C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\less.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
```

I am not sure what is causing this error. I removed cygwin from my windows registry. Is that the reason? In any case, how to get rid of this error?

Comment: I get the same error with Octave v3.8.2...

Comment: OP, @gaborous, you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Just uninstall Octave, then reboot, then reinstall it. This did the trick for me.

Comment: That ain't a solution.

Comment: This is the solution that solved the issue for me. I guess that the cygwin files were corrupted at some point (due to  computer crash or whatever), so uninstalling and reinstalling Octave restored them. It worked for me but if it does not help you maybe you have different issue :-/